# Is there a generic `str(int, base = n)` functionality in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int, radix

Ì am able to convert any `string` containing *digits and valid characters* (for that base) into an integer by specifying:

```
print ( int("ABCDEFGHIJKLMN", base=27) ) # for n in [0,2..36]
```

wich outputs `42246088999001073599`. [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

*I am interested in the generic reverse of that.* (up to 36 would be fine - same as `int()` does)

---

**Specialized solutions** available I know of:

```
bin() # binary string representation - with prefix
oct() # octal  string representation - with prefix
hex() # hexadecimal string representation - with prefix

str(num[, base=10] ) # for 0, 2..36
```

or you can use the [mini format language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to get the "pure" number string:

```
print(f"{32:o}") #  ==> 40 = 4*8+2=32
```

> ```
> Type  Meaning
> 'b'   Binary format. Outputs the number in base 2.
> 'o'   Octal format. Outputs the number in base 8.
> 'x'   Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using lower-case letters for the digits above 9.
> 'X'   Hex format. Outputs the number in base 16, using upper-case letters for the digits above 9.
> ```

I do not know of any generalized *`int to string of base n`* method.

---

I made one for base 12 in [my answer to a base 12 question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53778051/7505395):

> ```
> class Base12Convert:
>     d = {hex(te)[2:].upper():te for te in range(0,12)}
>     d.update({val:key for key,val in d.items()})
>     d["-"] = "-"
>
> # snipp: def text_to_int(text)
>
> @staticmethod
> def int_to_text(num):
>     """Converts an int into a base-12 string."""
>
>     sign = ""
>     if not isinstance(num,int):
>         raise ValueError(
>             f"Only integer as input allowed: '{num} of type {type(num)}' is invalid")
>     if num < 0:
>         sign = "-"
>         num *= -1
>
>     # get highest possible number
>     p = 1
>     while p < num:
>         p *= 12
>
>     # create string 
>     rv = [sign]
>     while True:
>         p /= 12
>         div = num // p
>         num -= div*p
>         rv.append(Base12Convert.d[div])
>         if p == 1:
>             break
>
>     return ''.join(rv)
> ```

and could generalize that ... but I probably overlook a built in_one?

Comment: No, you should write it yourself or try looking for modules on PyPI.

Comment: There's no generic answer, because there's no "universal dictionary", that will translate your integer to a string. Python chose to use 0-9 + a-z (w/o specifying the case) for base 2-36. But that was their decision. You could chose to translate to a different "dictionary" or even decide to make a difference of upper and lower case.

Comment: @MikeScotty there is a dictionary - but it is one-way as `int` maps `A..Z` to `10..35` if you give the correct base - I assumed that they also included an reverse but I never stumbled over it - seems there is none. Thanks.

Comment: I though you meant "generic" in a "for any value of ``n``" sense, so ``n`` could be even bigger than 36, which meant that the Python mapping of 0-9 + A-Z would not be enough. But there's indeed no built-in that I know of to reverse the string for base 2-36. Maybe use one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267362/how-to-convert-an-integer-in-any-base-to-a-string

Comment: @MikeScotty that did not pop up in my searched -thx. Closed as dupe.